# how many times a string contains a char in VBA

Tags: string, vba

is ther any way to know how many times a string contains a specific char?

e.g. how many times does the string "strin" contains a comma.

```
    Dim strin as strin
    strin = "qwe, asd, zcx"
```

Comment: I'm assuming `as strin` should be `as string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An old "trick" is to replace the string with something else, and check the difference in lengths of the string before and after doing the replace.

```
Dim replaced as string
replaced = Replace(strin, ",", "")
' count = Len(string) - Len(replaced)
```

If you had to count a multi-character string, like a comma and a space, you would have to divide the results by the length of the string you were replacing:

```
Dim replaced as string
replaced = Replace(strin, ", ", "")
' count = (Len(string) - Len(replaced)) / 2
```

Comment: Forgive me if I got the syntax wrong, been a long time since I did any VBA.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is to use a function.

The code below should do the trick.

```
sub TestCharCountFunction ' this sub is for testing the function

strin = "qwe, asd, zcx"

   msgbox  "Character appears " & charcounter( strin, "," ) & " time(s)"

end sub

function CharCounter (byval MyString as string, byval CharToSearch as string) as integer


dim X as integer

charcounter = 0

for X= 1 to len(mystring)

    if mid(mystring, x,1) = chartosearch then charcounter = charcounter + 1

next

end function
```